# Blur and change events on textarea elements, is there an equivalent of nochange on blur?

Tags: javascript, html

This question concerns the `change` and `blur` events on a `textarea`. If my understanding is accurate, the `change` event takes place only after the element loses the focus and there was a change to its `value` property.

It appears that the `change` event is part of the `blur` event and, if upon `blur` the `value` property has changed, then the `change` event is fired.

Is it possible to get information directly from the `blur` event that the `value` property has not changed, like a nochange event?

I realize that I can store the `value` of the textarea upon `focus` and then compare it upon `blur`, but thought it would be more efficient to use what the browser is already tracking if available.

Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: This unfortunately is an example of a so known "XY problem". (https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)
Please consider to expand a bit on the question, by answering `What problem are you trying to solve?`

Comment: And a [mcve] as well